# Translating whole swing

Tags: java, swing, localization

So, I have a program that I'd like to translate to Croatian...

But I've learned that swing may sometimes create dialogs and windows I have not expected (e.g. when trying to rename a file into existing name in JfolderChooser).

So instead of trying to expect the unexpected, I have decided to translate whole swing into Croatian and submit my translation to Oracle (or whoever I should) (if that is posible, I've heard it's encouraged). Then I can use Localization classes just to select my language and that's it (one day, at least)...

However, I don't really know how to do it, or which files of src folder to look into, so I need your help.

What (java) files do I look into, and what is standardized procedure of translating Swing into a new language?

Are there any other things I should do except dealing with language (like currency, etc.)?

And last of all, how do I submit it to Oracle?

Comment: You would would use resource bundles for this. Have you read the [Internationalization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/index.html) tutorial yet?

Comment: Yeah, but I'd like to translate the Swing so the translation could be implemented into Java 1.8 or 1.9 one day, if it's possible...
It currently has only limited number of languages supported (English, Italian, and about 10 more)... I'd like to add Croatian to the list...

Comment: You may need to propose adding Croatian to the [set of supported locales](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/locales-137662.html).

Comment: BTW, please take a look at [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/index). The translations for many things are already available, but it does not necessary mean that they want to include them in JDK. Few things that you are looking for (i.e. Currency) might be found in [ICU](http://icu-project.org/)

Comment: I intended to, but it would cost me a lot of time and money, it seems...

Comment: Excellent idea! Ako zatreba pomoc, tu sam :)

Comment: Hvala lijepa... =)
Bi li možda mogli razmjeniti neki(Facebook, Skype, etc.) kontakt nekako?

Comment: Ostavio sam mejl na svom stackoverflow profilu. Mozes mi poslati link od FB profila npr.

Comment: Da me ubiješ, ne mogu ga pronaći... Šalji mi mail na gmail, imam isti username kao ovdje...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, but it is very unlikely they will include your translations. That's just because once you include the translations for given language, you need to support it. Even though these translations doesn't change often, it is still rather serious effort and personally, I wouldn't risk including something that might soon be out of date.
There is a second side of this story: somebody has to review your translations. Believe it or not, it ain't cheap. So unless Oracle decide to crowd-source their translations for JDK, I am afraid you're out of luck.

On the other hand, most of the User Interface (actually all except for hardcoded strings...) could be translated by assigning appropriate [UIManager's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html) keys to translated values... This is quite an effort, but it can be done.
The problem here is, you don't know what keys are valid (or appropriate), so if you want to really translate the whole thing, you need to reverse engineer their controls (using the source code attached to JDK's distribution).

It is pretty surprising that we don't have sub-classed controls with externalized messages easily available... It is a common problem... I did something like this for my studies, but I am afraid I don't know where do localized JFileChooser is... I am pretty sorry about that.

Comment: In that case, I give up doing it for Oracle, but I still need it for my own needs.

Is there a way I could somehow write a class that would have aleast all the language values included and translated?

When it's on, everything is Croatian, when it's off, everyting is how it was?

I know about the UIManager, but I just can't believe that all languages key are not listet somewhere...

I kinda wanted to avoid loosing countless hours looking for that key in src folder...

Comment: It could be soooo simple...
If there was a list, all you had to do would be writing a method that would change all the values to desired (language) strings...